# How to find duplicate value of a column value using mysql?

Tags: mysql

I've a mysql table with the following data.

[image]

in the above image, some rows contains duplicate.

my question is how to find the repeated data in it?

```
For example : invoice_id = 19632, container duplicate data like BL No - NYKSMAAT20342300, Containers 3X40HC, 1X20GP and so on.
```

Pls help.

Comment: you have all in one column. That is terrible. Can you change the table structure?

Answer (score 1):

### Simple you can use this query to get duplicate entry from table

```
SELECT narration, COUNT(*) count FROM table GROUP BY narration HAVING count > 1;
```

Comment: Actually i've data like Chennai,Mumbai,Kolkata,Chennai,Bombay,Delhi,Mumbai. In the above content, i need to find Chennai and Mumbai Repeated twice. Hope understand my situation. kindly help me.